# Bug in iOS Camera recording EXIF Data

Tags: ios, iphone, exif

It appears there is a bug in EXIF/GPS data recorded on iOS devices.
Photos taken with iPhones record the GPSSpeedRef tag = "K" which implies kilometers per hour. This is not user selectable.  The other valid choices per the EXIF Standard are "M" for miles per hour or "N" for knots.

However, the data value in the GPSSpeed tag only makes sense as a value measured in meters per second, which of course is the units Apple reports speed in CoreLocation.

For example, I took a photo from the window of jet. My iPad ForeFlight app confirmed a ground speed of 540 mph, which translates to 870 kph. The EXIF GPSSpeed tag on the photo was = 240.75 which it turns out is in m/s units.

I've sent a Bug Report.

The Question: Aside from unwrapping the TIFF or MakerApple EXIF subdirectories, does anyone have a quick & reliable way to detect iOS-originated photos within a mixed source photo roll so I can special case the speed calculation? The MakerApple subdictionary is not always present, depending on originating device, and Model and Make tags in TIFF also seem to be unreliably present.

Comment: What GPSSpeedRef tags do you find in other mixed source images?I mean, do other camera's actually use K too? Other idea: look at the dimensions of the image; perhaps iOS camera's have unique dimensions?

Comment: So far, I have only examined the images created by several Sony and Canon pocket cams. They seems to follow the rules set forth in the EXIF Standard where a GPSSpeedRef of K actually means kph.